Black terrain when baking lightmap in Unity URP
I'm trying to bake a lightmap of my level in Unity URP. I've fixed issues with other objects; only the terrain remains. It just remains black, no matter what I do. It is checked as static and to contribute to GI. I don't know what else to try.

